# Dúvida sobre forma correta de estruturar componentes - REACT

Tags: javascript, react

sou novo com react e sempre fico com uma pulga atrás da orelha quando estou criando alguns componentes. Afinal, a forma correta de estruturar é assim

`<label>alo {nome}</label>`

ou criando uma const ou uma function que me retorne um label com os valores, eu estou falando de quando nós temos muitos componentes repetitivos... um amigo me disse que o código ficava menor e mais legível usando funções, mas em compensação ele decaia na performance pois chamava varias vezes a mesma função. Mas fico com o pé atrás em acreditar em qualquer coisa que me falem sem ter uma base concreta... Então pergunto a vocês, qual forma é a correta? se alguém puder dar junto a resposta uma explicação, fico muito agradecido.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, esse mesmo formato de label seria utilizado várias vezes no mesmo componente?

Comment: Aqui tem uma explicação que mostra a diferença de fazer o componente como classe ou como função https://medium.com/rocketseat/um-guia-para-iniciantes-no-react-js-80e1ac357649

Comment: Isso, o mesmo, G. Bittencout... Desculpa demorar a responder é pq esses dias eu estava acampando e não tinha internet. Muito Obrigado pelo Artigo Bins, Eu dei uma olhada e isso é exatamente o que eu estou aprendendo, sobre ciclo de vida dos componentes e tal, mas não é bem sobre isso a minha duvida(Pelo menos eu acho que não).

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou bem confusa, mas acredito que a leitura da seção [Pensando do jeito React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) disponível na documentação oficial pode te ajudar a assimilar vários conceitos básicos.

Answer (score 0):

Bom amigo diversos fatores podem influenciar isso... Primeiramente quando sabemos a hora correta de criar uma componente React? Simples, um componente é feito para reutilização então se você usa um determinado trecho de código em mais de um lugar, como por exemplo o **label** então está na hora de abstrair isso.

Agora referente a criar uma função como você disse ou escrever direto o código, vamos usar um simples exemplo:

Temos a seguinte situação uma lista de tarefas:

```
const todoList = ["fazer café", "lavar as mãos", "guardar a louca"]
```

Agora temos que nós perguntar... Oque ficaria mais fácil? Vou te apresentar duas soluções, a primeira é a seguinte:

```
function List(props) {
  const todoList = ["fazer café", "lavar as mãos", "guardar a louca"]

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{todoList[0]}</li>
      <li>{todoList[1]}</li>
      <li>{todoList[2]}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

export default list;
```

Também podemos fazer:

```
 import React from 'react';

  function List(props) {
    const todoList = ["fazer café", "lavar as mãos", "guardar a louca"]

    return (
      <ul>
        { todoList.map(value => <li>{value}</li>) }
      </ul>
    );
  }

  export default list;
```

Já nesse caso é bem viável você criar um componente pois isso pode ser reutilizado em outros lugares além de que você não fica apegado ao código estático... 
A chave é pensar pois cada caso é um caso.